# Check if user is in current domain

Tags: web, vbscript, asp-classic

We have a website that is public and one that is internal.

We want the one that is internal to be accessed only for those that are connected to the network of our company. But it's not only that.
The problem here is that some pages in our internal needs to be accessed from the public and some not.

I tried to get the domain name of the computer of the user, but I'm getting the one from the server that is hosting our WebSite. The code was something like that :

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strUserDomain = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERDOMAIN%")
response.Write("User Domain: " & strUserDomain)
```

EDIT : I'm trying to get the domain of the user accessing our Website to know if he is one of our employees. It not, I don't want anyone from the outside accessing those pages. If there is an other way to do that, I would gladly accept an other solution if it's detailed.

EDIT : I'm using VBScript and our Website is in ASP.

Comment: Are you using ASP? Do the users have to authenticate? Can you distinguish them by client IP address? Why are you mixing internal and external access in the first place?

Comment: I wrote VBScript in the title yesterday, but it somehow disappeared. No they don't have to authenticate to enter the Website. I could distinguish them by their IP, I'm just trying to find a solution to this.
It's kind of complicated for why we have two websites. The public one is like our new website and the internal is our old one. But we are using some old pages of the old one in the new one. That's something you don't see everyday.

Comment: It didn't disappear. I removed it, because you shouldn't put a tags in the title. Tags belong in the tags field. Also, the VBScript tag applies to plain VBScript as well as HTA and ASP. To me it looks like you're using ASP. However, your question is far too incomplete for us to answer, since we know nothing about your environment or access patterns.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know and I added it in the post. I also edited my text to be more explicit saying what was edited. I hope it's better.